# VueJS Router: $route is not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

This is my component:

```js
const Vue = require("vue/dist/vue.js");
const qs = require("querystring");

module.exports = Vue.component("Page",function(resolve){
    console.log($route);
    let id = this.$route.params.id;
    fetch("/getPage.json",{
        method:"POST",
        body:qs.stringify({
            id
        })
    }).then(r=>r.json())
    .then(j=>{
        console.log(j);
        resolve({
            template:`<h1>`+JSON.stringify(j)+"</h1>"
        });
    })
});
```

And this is my router:

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
 mode:"history",
 routes:[
  {
   path:"/",
   component:Home
  },
  {
   path:"/me",
   component:Me
  },
  {
   path:"/create-page",
   component:createPage
  },
  {
   path:"/p/:id",
   component:Page
  }
 ]
});
Vue.use(VueRouter);
```

When i run this app i get:

`ReferenceError: $route is not defined`

I tried using `this.$route` but it's not working. I'm using an arrow function. When i do this it works:

```js
const Vue = require("vue/dist/vue.js");

module.exports = Vue.component("Page",function(resolve){
  resolve({
    template:`<h1>{{$route.params.id}}`
  });
});
```

Please help me figure out how to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

in your main vue app

```
new Vue(...)
```

you have to use vue-router first

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter)
...
new Vue(...)
...
```

and the go ahead with route declaration

Comment: I am using ``Vue.use(VueRouter)``.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to add `router` in `Vue` instance

in you main.js or app.js or index.js (entry point)

```
const app = new Vue({
  router
})
```

[documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/getting-started.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT use arrow functions

```
data: function() {
    return {
      usertype: this.$route.params.type
    };
  },
```

This worked for me.